# How to Implement MS Azure AD Authentication in ASP.NET Web application through Forms?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am developing a web application, which multiple login options like forms/google/open ldap/ Azure AD

Please guide me how to implement MS Assure based AD authentication.

I am using a custom login page where users enter can enter login name and password.. This should be validated at Azure AD server and return a status. Rest of the login procedures are already created.
Also looking for a method to fetch the users Full Name, email address from AD server to show on screens and update user records on local database.

Comment: Check the [Microsoft identity platform (v2.0) overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview). Also, please refer to [ask], since this question in its current form is way too broad and no fit for SO.

Comment: What kind of application is this? SPA? What programming language or framework are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your requirement using [Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview) in which you can provide multiple identity providers.

If it's only with the authentication of Multiple identifiers you can choose Azure Ad B2C [user flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows)(Provides Sign-In/Sign-Up/Profile Edit/Password Reset) which is easier to implement.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple answer to such a huge question, you must learn more from Microsoft docs.
At first step, you must read something about the whole platform, please read overview doc about Microsoft identity platform: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview

You wrote that you are building ASP.NET Web application with login, so the next steps are:
1. Quickstart: Add Microsoft identity platform sign-in to an ASP.NET web app https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-webapp
2. Step by step tutorial for ASP.NET web app: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp
3. A sample showcasing how to develop a web application that handles sign-on via the unified Azure AD and MSA endpoint: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapp-openidconnect

Basic user data exists within ID tokens.
The following paragraph shows how to get user name and e-mail in the ASP.NET web app:
https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp#add-a-controller-to-display-users-claims